# Django - Reload model definition runtime - metaclass

Tags: python, django, model, metaclass, entity-attribute-value

I'm writing a model class based on EAV paradigm. The implementation is based on python metaclass that is responsible to "create" the model interface so all django features (admin, forms, class base views,...) can work without any further changes.

The model definition (fields list and related type) is done using the admin interface.

What I'm not able to do is to reload the model on save event after any changes is made in the admin interface. It's clear that the solution is very useful only if I can do the model changes without the need of restart the engine.

Is there a way to force the model reload for a django model without restarting the engine?

Comment: You should post a minimal working example of what you are trying, otherwise things get hard to answer. You likely are not recording your modified model to a ".py" file and forcing  a "reload" - so, without knowing how you hold your model, there is no way to help.  IIRC Django have some internal attributes it anottates that it is in "initializing" state  -reading models and such - and "initialized" - all models and cross references are considered as read. You will have to force django to "reinitialize" - and I am not sure if there is a public api for that.

Comment: https://github.com/biggosh/kvform here you can find a more or less working POC